# Before & After Image Hover Code?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I'm remaking my retouching portfolio and need a code that changes the image to the "before" image when hovered over.

I need something like [this](http://www.glennferon.com/portfolio1/portfolio62.html)

However, I'm not building this site from scratch. I am either going to use 4ormat, Cargocollective, Squarespace, Prosite, or anything else that will support this code I need.

I've found several codes online and tried to practice and implement them into a tumblr theme but none of them worked. Everything I found made it sound very simple and easy to do, I'm just very unexperienced in this.

So basically I need a code that I can implement into a portfolio website so when I hover over the photos it goes to the before photos. Hopefully someone here can help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: add a fiddle of what you tried.

Comment: this is not hard to do, just use 2 images laying on each other and both are contained in the same parent, the `:hover` should be applied on the parent, it can also be applied on one of the image but to hide the image you have to use opacity...

Comment: I tried to do [this one](http://kaidez.com/tutorial-simple-effective-jquery-image-rollover/) and a few similar ones but they didn't seem to work. It could be because I was trying them in Tumblr and it didn't support it. But I didn't want to pay for a portfolio and try it there if they didn't support it. Which brings me here!

Comment: @KingKing that's what everyone online says, yet I can't get it to work. If you could give me an example code of what you mean I would appreciate it, because I only know basic HTML/CSS. Sorry for my lack of knowledge on this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your photos are the primary content, you should avoid the use of background images. If the before and after are always the same dimensions then we can make it really simple.

Have a fiddle - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/Z86BT/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="photo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="before" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500/FF0000" class="after" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.photo {
    position: relative;
}
.photo .after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
.photo .before:hover + .after, .after:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I need. Now, do you have any advice of where I would implement that code into a already pre-made theme so it applies to the whole site? I wish I had the code to show you right now but I haven't paid for my portfolio site yet to get one.

Comment: I edited my answer slightly. Apply a class of whatever name to the div and target that specifically. In your style CSS file place this snippet of CSS right at the bottom, should be fine :) If there are conflicts, you just need to overwrite them in these CSS styles.

Comment: Great! Really appreciate it. I'll give this a try when I can and hopefully it will work for me. I'll come back here if I get confused.

Comment: Often these themes will have something like `styles.css` that can easily be added to or changed. Remember that each group of before and after photos need to be in their own `div`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have your image/div with the id "myImage":

```
<div id="myImage"> </div>
```

In CSS you define both the path of your image when not hovered, and the path when hovered:

```
#myImage
{
background-image: url("oldpath");
}

#myImage :hover
{
background-image: url("newpath");
}
```

Comment: Would that be something I could edit in a pre-made theme and have it apply to all the images on my site after that?

Comment: I don't know about that pre-made theme but you should be able to add code there aren't you? And yes you would have to do it for every image which you want to change on hover...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

You can use this for anywhere . ALso good for Dynamic Images.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/shanulinxys/3XrLe/)

HTML

```
<div>
<img width="200" src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTQvh3lPZDFKZQ-EXNHfK-YuyeUNque_YuZSuMIWw0i0QPziuFG" data-hover="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ74BKYRIOhmeSFtyNzP_tgf-rjeUTykfXQQ8tY_xwn3GXF_6fW"/>
```

Jquery

```
$( "img" ).hover(
function() 
  {
      var $originalimg = $(this).attr("src"); 
      var $secimage    = $(this).attr("data-hover");
      $(this).attr("src",$secimage);
      $(this).attr("data-hover",$originalimg);
  }, 
  function() 
  {
       $(this).attr("src",$originalimg);
  }
```

);